# what is the command to install smptplib on windows

Tags: python

I've tried to install smtplib on my windows PC using `pip` and `easy_install` but running into below errors,can anyone point me how to install smtplib on windows?

```
C:\>pip install smtplib
Collecting smtplib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for smtplib

C:\CST_QSPR\third_party_bin\BuildLoaderScripts\Android\cnss_image_loader>easy_install smtplib
Searching for smtplib
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/smtplib/
Couldn't find index page for 'smtplib' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for smtplib
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('smtplib')
```

Comment: It's builtin module, isn't it? [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html), [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)

Comment: just import it.

Comment: @tinySandy - If I import it I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnss_image_loader.py", line 24, in <module>
    import smtplib, email, string
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 44, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: You have wrong version of python for your computer architecture

Comment: I am using `Python 2.7.9` which is fine

Comment: what python version is needed?

Comment: Check your system, it's either x86 or 64. Uninstall python completely and download proper installer

Comment: thanks,installing 64bit python 2.7.9 fixed the issue

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is a built in module so you can just import it without worry.

Answer (score 1):

I am using python3.9.6. When I tried using `pip install smtplib`, I got the same error as yours. After some little research I got the solution:

- Using `pip install secure-smtplib` for installation.
- Then `import smtplib` for importation

Answer (score 0):

I believe using pip install secure-smtplib would give same result

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you think like that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Installing smtplib in Windows

1. Install using **smtplib** command in command prompt:

```
    pip install smtplib
```

Received Error message stating

```
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/smtplib/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for smtplib
```

2. If couldn't install using above command try installing using **secure-smtplib** command in command prompt:

```
pip install secure-smtplib
```

To know more about secure-smtp visit https://pypi.org/project/secure-smtplib/
Successfull installation gives below message

```
Collecting secure-smtplib
Downloading secure_smtplib-0.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Installing collected packages: secure-smtplib
Successfully installed secure-smtplib-0.1.1
```

3. If unable to install smtplib using secure-smtplib check for version of python used. Installation of secure-smtplib needs wheel installation which works only for Python version 2.7 visit https://pypi.org/project/secure-smtplib/#files to get more idea.If not using Python 2.7 download 2.7 version and make sure python interpreter is set for python2.7 version